# How to create haskell permutation

Tags: function, haskell, boolean, permutation

What i want to do is create a function that given a certain length creates all possible combinations/permutations of True/False

ex. `getPerm 2` shall return `[True,True,True,False,False,True,False,False]`

```
getTrue 0 = []
getTrue size = (True:(getTrue (size-1)))++(True:(getFalse (size-1)))
getFalse 0 = []
getFalse size =(False:(getTrue (size-1)))++(False:(getFalse (size-1)))
getPerm 0 = []
getPerm size= (getTrue size)++(getFalse size)
```

I can't get it right..im new to functional programming so please only use basic stuff and not weird things..try to make code as simple as possible cuz i don't know a lot about haskell yet

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
getPerm n = concat $ replicateM n [True, False]
```

While it might qualify as a "weird thing", it isn't too hard. `[True, False]` represents nondeterministic choice in the list monad. `replicateM` makes a nondeterministic list of `n` repetitions of these choices. Since you wanted them all in one list we concatenate to get the final result.

Comment: `replicateM` makes `n` copies of a computation and collects the results in a list. So for example `replicateM 10 getLine` would read 10 lines and collect them in a list. Here I'm using it in the list monad, so it repeats a choice between `True` and `False` n times and gives you all the possible resulting lists.

Comment: It's essentially the same as FUZxxl's solution, since `replicateM = sequence . replicate`.

Comment: You need to import `Control.Monad`.

Comment: okay now it works, but as far as i undestand from the line concat $ replicateM n [True, False] is that i replicate [True,False] n times then concat them in 1 list which should make the pattern result like [True,False,True,False,True,False,True,False,...] and not work correctly :D sorry i ask a lot but i really want to learn :)

Comment: Okay thanks a lot i googled and understood what i want :) was really helpful guys :D

Answer (score 3):

You get your result by using `sequence`:

```
getPerm = concat . sequence . flip replicate [True,False]
```

If you want to have different lists for all permutations, just drop the `concat`.

I just thought of a more basic definition. `iterate :: (a -> a) -> a -> [a]` applies a function again and again and returns the intermediate values:

```
getPerm = concat . (iterate permute [[]] !!)

permute xs = map (True:) xs ++ map (False:) xs
```

So basically, `permute` generates the next permutation, while `getPerm` just picks the permutation needed.

Comment: I tried this line and it worked, but can u please explain? i don't get what this . exactly is?! flip replicate is kind off clear and you used currying for the size.

Comment: `.` is function composition. That is, `f . g = \x -> f (g x)`

Answer (score 2):

Here's another perspective.

`getPerm n` is going to create 2^n permutations.  Another way of generating these values is simply to count from 0 to 2^n-1 and encode the bit pattern as `True` and `False`.

I've changed the type of your `getPerms` function to return a list of lists so that it is easier to break things apart.

```
import Data.Bits

getPerms :: Int -> [[Bool]]
getPerms n = map (encode n) [0..2^n-1]

encode :: Int -> Int -> [Bool]
encode bitSize value = map (testBit value) [0..bitSize-1]

*Main> getPerms 2
[[False,False],[True,False],[False,True],[True,True]]
```

Comment: Good point either. You may want to add, that the OP has to `import Data.Bits` for `testBit`.